# Как заставить двигаться html при помощи js setInterval()

Tags: javascript, html, css

Делаю секундную стрелку на часах, она устанавливается правильно, но не перемещается. Как решить данную проблему?

```
let timerId = setInterval(() => updateClock(), 1000);

function updateClock() {
    updateSeconds();
}

function updateSeconds() {
    let deg = 6 * seconds;
    secondsArrow.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно было получать дату в функции, которая вызывается каждую секунду)

```
function updateSeconds() {
    let now = new Date();
    let seconds = now.getSeconds();
    let deg = 6 * seconds;
    secondsArrow.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
}
```